# Why won't this print the first two numbers, then the next two and so on?

Tags: java

```
    public class DeleteLater {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String test = "12345678";
            int x;
            for (x = 0; x < test.length(); x++){
            System.out.println(test.substring(x, x));
            x++;
        }
    }
```

I want it to print "12" and then "34" and then "56".

Comment: In addition to the desired result, please include the actual result.

Answer (score 1):

The substring you are getting has the same start index as the end index.

You can do more than just count(++ or --) "i" in the header of the for loop.
You can do calculations in there like:

```
i += 2
```

in this case "+=" means the same as:

```
i = i + 2
```

You can try the following:

```
public class DeleteLater {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "12345678";
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < test.length() - 1; x += 2) {
            System.out.println(test.substring(x, x + 2));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        String test = "12345678 ";
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < test.length()-1; x=x+2)
        {
            System.out.println(test.substring(x, x + 2));
        }
```

This should work (haven't tested), you need to display numbers in groups of two, I suppose, so we need to display 2 characters, and then move to the third character, skipping the second.

In this loop we are displaying two characters, then updating the loop variable by +2, to go two indexes further in the string.

Also, as per my knowledge, the substring function does not return the character of the second index provided, so adding a space or any extra character might save it from an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.
(More details on that : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

Of course, shorthands and escapes can then be used for more efficiency.

Please do let me know if there are any errors or doubts :)

Answer (score 0):

In order to print like this, you need character at current index, and character at next index. If you know you never have odd number of characters, you can do it like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "12345678";
        for (int index = 0; index < test.length(); index+=2) {
            String value = test.substring(index, index + 2);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
```

But in the case of `123456789` for example you get exception. If you need to take such cases into account, you can do it like this:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String test = "123456789";
        //index step is 2, because we get the next inside loop
        for (int index = 0; index < test.length(); index+=2) {
            char currentChar = test.charAt(index);
            String next;
            int nextIndex = index + 1;
            if (nextIndex < test.length()) {
                //if next index is inside bounds, add character at this index
                next = Character.toString(test.charAt(nextIndex));
            } else {
                //if not, init with empty string
                next = "";
            }
            String value = currentChar + next;
            System.out.println(value);
        }
    }
```

This works both with even and odd length of input.

Answer (score -1):

first, you should use methods instead of writing all of the code in the main method to make it more clear
and then you need to know how the substring method works
check this code out

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printTwoNumbers();
}

private static void printTwoDigits() {
    String test = "12345678";
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x < test.length(); x+=2)
        System.out.println(test.substring(x, x+2));
}
```

Comment: One - for example purposes, including code in main is fine. Two - what happens in your loop when x = 7?

Comment: x+=2 means that x will be in range : 0 ,2,4,6,8,10 and so on 
it will never be 7